# PyBuilder: No unit tests executed

Tags: python, python-unittest, pybuilder

Suppose that this is the layout of the source directory of my PyBuilder project
(empty `__init__.py` in `myProject` omitted):

```
src
├── main
│   └── python
│       └── myProject
│           └── usefulThing.py
└── unittest
    └── python
        └── UsefulThingTest.py
```

and the content of `UsefulThingTest.py` is as follows:

```
import unittest

from myProject.usefulThing import usefulFunction

class UsefulThingTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_should_do_useful_things(self):
    self.assertEqual(usefulFunction(42), 1764)
```

When I run `pyb`, I get the following warnings, and no tests are executed:

```
[WARN]  No unit tests executed.
[INFO]  All unit tests passed.
```

Why doesn't PyBuilder run those tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the `UsefulThingTest`-class extends `unittest.TestCase` is not sufficient for the class to be run as a test. The name of the file in which `UsefulThingTest` is saved must also follow a convention: by default, it must end with `_tests.py`. For example, renaming:

```
UsefulThingTest.py
```

to

```
useful_thing_tests.py
```

fixes the problem.

Quote from the [Tutorial](http://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/tutorial.html):

> The file must end with `_tests.py`. This tells PyBuilder to consider this file when discovering test cases.

This can be altered by setting the `unittest_file_suffix` property as [described here](http://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/plugins.html#Pythonunittestproperties).

Answer (score 0):

unittests require file (containing tests) to be named as:
 *_tests.py

And it also imposes restrictions on functions name:

```
import unittest
class SampleTests(unittest.TestCase):
      def test1(self):
          #function name should be like this : no underscore etc.
```

i.e They have predefined naming conventions for test suite